# Expected JSON payload not returning proper JSON payload

Tags: php, api, json

I am using the following code to parse some JSON and I keep getting an unexpected JSON result.

It is originally from [here](https://gist.github.com/matthewtole/6185636), but I couldn't get that code working because on Line 57 `$status` was not an array so it was throwing an error relating to the fact that `$status` was not an array:

I fixed that by adding a check:

```
56 if (is_array($status)) {}
```

Now the code runs fine but the JSON returned is the following:

```
{"0":null,"1":" 0"}
```

I know this is not correct, because when I run [an application](https://github.com/smallstoneapps/london-tube/) on my Pebble Watch it is meant to display the proper data and obviously fails because there is none within `0`.

As far as I can tell the following code should insert `$order` in place of `null` but it's always returning `null` instead for some reason.

```
35  // Grab the tube status and the incoming payload.
36  $tube_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($API_URL), true);
37  $payload = get_payload();
38  
39  $order = $payload['0'];
40  
41  // Start building the response.
42  $response = array(
43    '0' => $order,
44    '1' => ''
45  );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Here is the complete code (including utils):

**main.php**

```
1  <?php
2  
3  // Include my shared functions.
4  include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/utils.php');
5  
6  // The URL of the Tube Status API.
7  $API_URL = 'http://api.tubeupdates.com/?method=get.status&format=json';
8  
9  // Mapping between shortcode and line name.
10  $line_codes = array(
11    'BL' => 'bakerloo',
12    'CE' => 'central',
13    'CI' => 'circle',
14    'DI' => 'district',
15    'DL' => 'docklands',
16    'HC' => 'hammersmithcity',
17    'JL' => 'jubilee',
18    'ME' => 'metropolitan',
19    'NO' => 'northern',
20    'OV' => 'overground',
21    'PI' => 'piccadilly',
22    'VI' => 'victoria',
23    'WC' => 'waterloocity'
24  );
25  
26  // Mapping between errors and numbers
27  $statuses = array(
28    'good service' => 1,
29    'part closure' => 2,
30    'minor delays' => 4,
31    'severe delays' => 8,
32    'part suspended' => 16
33  );
34  
35  // Grab the tube status and the incoming payload.
36  $tube_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($API_URL), true);
37  $payload = get_payload();
38  
39  $order = $payload['0'];
40  
41  // Start building the response.
42  $response = array(
43    '0' => $order,
44    '1' => ''
45  );
46  
47  // Split the ordering string into the 2 character line short codes.
48  $lines = str_split($order, 2);
49  foreach ($lines as $pos => $line) {
50  
51    // Get the status for the line given its short code.
52    $status = get_status_by_id($line_codes[$line]);
53  
54    // Do bitwise ORs on the status number to build it up
55    $status_number = 0;
56    if (is_array($status)) {
57      foreach ($status as $st) {
58        $status_number = $status_number |= $statuses[$st];
59      }
60    }
61  
62    // Append the status code to the response string.
63    $response['1'] .= str_pad($status_number, 2, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
64  }
65  
66  // Send the response.
67  send_response($response);
68  
69  // Takes a line code (not shortcode) and returns an array of its current status.
70  function get_status_by_id($id) {
71    global $tube_data;
72  
73    foreach ($tube_data['response']['lines'] as $index => $line) {
74      if ($line['id'] == $id) {
75        return explode(', ', $line['status']);
76      }
77    }
78    return NULL;
79  }
80  
81  ?>
```

**utils.php**

```
<?php

function get_payload() {
    return json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}

function send_response($data) {
    $response = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($response));
    echo $response;
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expected JSON payload not returning properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139137/expected-json-payload-not-returning-properly)

Comment: @gotnull does my answer below address your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect the consumer, if it's literally returning the word 'null' in the json string  `{"0":null,"1":" 0"}`, just do a string replace and replace the pattern null with ''.

```
 $payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $payload = str_replace(' null ', '""', $payload);
 return json_decode($payload, true);
```

To fix  send_response() so it never includes 'null' as a result you can iterrate through the array before encoding it to either:

1. change any null into an empty string.
2. delete any index pointing to a null

I like number 1:

```
function send_response($data) {
    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
           $data[$key] = is_null($value) ? '' : $value;
    }
    $response = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($response));
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
```